# how to add this github project to use in ruby class

Tags: ruby, class, rubygems

I am learning how to use the data structure in ruby.

I found this library on github : https://github.com/kanwei/algorithms/tree/master.

I have created a word_count.rb file locally.
I want to use the library I mentioned, locally in my ruby class file.

## The link I mentioned has following project structure :

[image]

how can I use this project in class file ?

Comment: Don't make us go to Github just to understand what you're trying to do. Instead, you are supposed to include a summarized version of that information *in your question*. *WHEN* that link breaks it will make your question nonsensical instantly without that. In addition, what have you tried? You need to show your attempt to make this work, instead of simply asking for someone to do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is published as a gem (just the page you found does not document that fact): https://rubygems.org/gems/algorithms

So if you have a `Gemfile` in your project, add the line:

```
gem "algorithms", "~> 0.6.1"
```

Otherwise, run the following command:

```
gem install algorithms
```

and use it like you would any other gem, with

```
require 'algorithms'
```

in one of your source files.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'algorithms'
include Containers
```

http://kanwei.github.io/algorithms/